Apps script to create dependant Dropdown in google form
Based on an google sheet containing 3 columns :
col 1 contains department codes,
col 2 contains city names,
col 3 contains establishment names,
Here is the link to the google sheets that I'm using as a source for the form
I am trying to have a code that would generate a google form breaked into sections containing questions with answer items filtered depending on the answer to previous question, i.e., I would like that depending on the department code selected, only cities of this department are available in the next section asking to select a city, and depending on the selected city, only the establishments of the city are avaiblable in the last section asking to select an establishement.
I have this code that works for departments and cities
see the google form that is generated with the bellow code
const FORM_ID="1OkH_GNjrvOCkiBAXKqmRQq3e1uYxEpE8baqEDVokFso"
let form=FormApp.openById(FORM_ID)
function resetForm(){
let items=form.getItems()
items.forEach(item=>form.deleteItem(item))
}
function createConditionalForm(){
resetForm()
let ws=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
let ss=ws.getSheetByName("Feuille 4")
let table=ss.getDataRange().getValues()
table.shift()
let dptOptions=table.map(row=>row[0])
let singleDptOptions=[]
dptOptions.forEach(option=>{
if(singleDptOptions.indexOf(option)==-1)
singleDptOptions.push(option)
})
let departementQuestion = form.addMultipleChoiceItem().setTitle("Select Region")
let finalDptOptions = []
singleDptOptions.forEach(dptOption=>{
let section=form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle(dptOption)
section.setGoToPage(FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT)

let cityOptions=table.filter(option=>option[0]==dptOption).map(row=>row[1])
let singleCityOptions=[]
cityOptions.forEach(option=>{
if(singleCityOptions.indexOf(option)==-1)
singleCityOptions.push(option)
})
let cityQuestion = form.addMultipleChoiceItem().setTitle("Select City")
cityQuestion.setChoiceValues(singleCityOptions)
let dptChoice = departementQuestion.createChoice(dptOption, section)
finalDptOptions.push(dptChoice)
})
departementQuestion.setChoices(finalDptOptions)
}

but I don't manage to add another section with establishements after the city selection.
Here is what where I am so far, but I keep geting error messages saying that the array is empty.
const FORM_ID="Form_ID"
let form=FormApp.openById(FORM_ID)
function resetForm(){
let items=form.getItems()
items.forEach(item=>form.deleteItem(item))
}
function createConditionalForm(){
resetForm()
let ws=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
let ss=ws.getSheetByName("Feuille 4")
let table=ss.getDataRange().getValues()
table.shift()
let dptOptions=table.map(row=>row[0])
let singleDptOptions=[]
dptOptions.forEach(option=>{
if(singleDptOptions.indexOf(option)==-1)
singleDptOptions.push(option)
})
let departementQuestion = form.addMultipleChoiceItem().setTitle("Select Dpt code")
let finalDptOptions = []
singleDptOptions.forEach(dptOption=>{
let section=form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle(dptOption)
let cityOptions=table.filter(option=>option[0]==dptOption).map(row=>row[1])
let singleCityOptions=[]
cityOptions.forEach(option=>{
if(singleCityOptions.indexOf(option)==-1)
singleCityOptions.push(option)
})
let cityQuestion = form.addMultipleChoiceItem().setTitle("Select City")
let finalCityOptions=[]
singleCityOptions.forEach(cityOption=>{
let section2=form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle(cityOption)
section2.setGoToPage(FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT)
let etabOptions=table.filter(option=>option[0]==cityOption).map(row=>row[2])
let singleEtabOptions=[]
etabOptions.forEach(option=>{
if(singleEtabOptions.indexOf(option)==-1)
singleEtabOptions.push(option)
})
let etabQuestion=form.addMultipleChoiceItem().setTitle("Select Place")
etabQuestion.setChoiceValues(singleEtabOptions)
let cityChoice = cityQuestion.createChoice(cityOption, section2)
finalCityOptions.push(cityChoice)
})
cityQuestion.setChoices(finalCityOptions)
cityQuestion.setChoiceValues(singleCityOptions)
let dptChoice = departementQuestion.createChoice(dptOption, section)
finalDptOptions.push(dptChoice)
})
departementQuestion.setChoices(finalDptOptions)
}

Any clue how I can adapt the inital code ?
Thanks for your help !

Kindly share a minimal, reproducible example—no sensitive data with your desired output—that the community can use to replicate and see what you'd like to do. You may use Tables or tools like Table to Markdown that can easily be copied and pasted. If necessary, as a last resort, Make an anonymous sample document.

Hello @Saddles i've added the link of the google sheets ! thanks !

You've written a LOT of code. Have you tried to manually create a proof-of-concept using a Google Form?

hi @Tedinoz ! Yes and here is the link to the form generated with the first code and that works well. I'm just blocked for the part where I wand to add a last section after the city slection : [https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdGy1EQcZVWwTpqa_X7HsS9aiC-q0E_OCicEoTXGCwBDyspjg/viewform?usp=header]

here is the link to the form I've run that, and there must be some difference because the city selections under each department are configured to "Continue to next Section" rather than "Submit". Correction: "Go to section based on answer" doesn't seem to be set.

@Tedinoz thanks ! Are you sure ? when I run it and try the form, the city selection goes to the send form button [https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1OkH_GNjrvOCkiBAXKqmRQq3e1uYxEpE8baqEDVokFso/previewResponse]

part where I'm having trouble is to have a similar loop after the city selection, with the list of establishments

I might have been a little vague there - Your linked form is fine. Script#1 in the question  doesn't continue to submit.

@Tedinoz I've repasted the code in the first part from the linked form.

FYI: Duplicate enties: 75,Paris,Collège privé Saint-Louis has two entries; ditto 75, Paris 8e Arrondissement, Ecole Canadienne de Paris; ditto 77, Meaux, Lycée Henri Moissan. Plus there are 30 department/cities with a blank Establishment; of these 75, Paris 16e Arrondissement has four entries; 75, Paris 17e Arrondissement has two entries; 75, Paris 19e Arrondissement has two entries.

@Tedinoz thanks ! I noticed and will clean the data. On my side still working on the spcript, trying to add the last section with the establishments. Let me know if you have something and many thanks for your help


This is to point out what the problem is in the original code.

When the script is tested, it seems that the error Exception: Array is empty: values shows up, which is what I believe you meant by the statement keep geting error messages saying that the array is empty.
Upon reviewing the code, the cause of the error is
let etabOptions = table.filter(option => option[0] == cityOption).map(row => row[2]);

The script is filtering Département, which is option[0], not Nom_commune, which is option[1].
You may change that to:
let etabOptions = table.filter(option => option[1] == cityOption).map(row => row[2]);

The full code would become:
const FORM_ID = "Form_ID";
let form = FormApp.openById(FORM_ID);

function resetForm() {
  let items = form.getItems();
  items.forEach(item => form.deleteItem(item));
}

function createConditionalForm() {
  resetForm();
  let ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let ss = ws.getSheetByName("Feuille 5");
  let table = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  table.shift();
  let dptOptions = table.map(row => row[0]);
  let singleDptOptions = [];
  dptOptions.forEach(option => {
    if (singleDptOptions.indexOf(option) == -1) {
      singleDptOptions.push(option);
    }
  });
  let departementQuestion = form.addMultipleChoiceItem().setTitle("Select Region");
  let finalDptOptions = [];
  singleDptOptions.forEach(dptOption => {
    let section = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle(dptOption);
    section.setGoToPage(FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT);
    let cityOptions = table.filter(option => option[0] == dptOption).map(row => row[1]);
    let singleCityOptions = [];
    cityOptions.forEach(option => {
      if (singleCityOptions.indexOf(option) == -1) {
        singleCityOptions.push(option);
      }
    });
    let cityQuestion = form.addMultipleChoiceItem().setTitle("Select City");
    let finalCityOptions = [];
    singleCityOptions.forEach(cityOption => {
      let section2 = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle(cityOption);
      section2.setGoToPage(FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT);
      let etabOptions = table.filter(option => option[1] == cityOption).map(row => row[2]);
      let singleEtabOptions = [];
      etabOptions.forEach(option => {
        if (singleEtabOptions.indexOf(option) == -1) {
          singleEtabOptions.push(option);
        }
      });
      let etabQuestion = form.addMultipleChoiceItem().setTitle("Select Place");
      etabQuestion.setChoiceValues(singleEtabOptions);
      let cityChoice = cityQuestion.createChoice(cityOption, section2);
      finalCityOptions.push(cityChoice);
    });
    cityQuestion.setChoices(finalCityOptions);
    let dptChoice = departementQuestion.createChoice(dptOption, section);
    finalDptOptions.push(dptChoice);
  });
  departementQuestion.setChoices(finalDptOptions);
}

Notes:

Be wary of Quotas for Google Services. I've tested this on a small sample from what you provided to make sure it's working, since the original data took about 11 minutes and 20 seconds to complete.
Semicolons are optional in JavaScript. However, I've still added them at the end of the lines in the script as best practice.
There are no curly braces { } at the end of your conditional statements. This syntax is perfectly valid, but it is much easier to understand the code if you use the curly braces to delimit the blocks of code, and use multiple lines and indentation.


Many thanks @Saddles ! I tried the code but I get a message saying that it exceeds maximum execution time... :(

I understand. The large data size causes it to exceed the maximum execution time. Script runtime is 6 min / execution, and I'm guessing that the only reason it completed for me with the entire example is because I was using a Google Workspace account. Try it on smaller data to see if that's the expected output you're looking for. The purpose of my answer is to point out what the problem is in the original code.

By the way, keep in mind what @Tedinoz's NOTE#2 said. There are 8 regions, 471 unique cities and 1,641 establishments in the spreadsheet. When the script completed in the original data, the performance of the form wasn't great as it kept being unresponsive.

Thanks a lot for you help ! I will keep the structure of the code for other usecases and will look for alternatives for this one. Many thanks !!

You want to create dependant dropdowns based on region, city (within a region) and establishment (within region/city). You are having difficulty getting the relevant establishments.
The hierarchy of data reflects the order of processing within the script:

get a list of unique regions

for each unique region, get a list of unique cities

for each unique region/unique city, get the establishments





The logic of the following script follows this hierarchy.
This statement:
Logger.log("DEBUG: Region = "+dptOption+"\ncity name = "+uniqueCityName+"\nestablishments = "+regionCityEstablishment) has been left uncommented; it allows the OP to scan/view the results generated by the script.
FWIW, a sample of results have been confirmed by comparison to the source data.
NOTE#1: the script does NOT create the form - that is a separate task. However the steps for this are simplified having identified each region, unique cities within a region and establishments with each unique city with each region.
NOTE#2: One must question the effectiveness and responsiveness of the final Form. There are 8 regions, 471 unique cities and 1,641 establishments. So far as the user experience is concerned, in many cases the number of options extends into the hundreds. So far as responsiveness of the Form is concerned, one must accept that the performance of a form containing several hundred sections may not acceptable. It is, perhaps, something on which the OP might reflect and consider possible options.
Analysis of Regions/Cities and Estblishments


const FORM_ID="insert your form ID"
let form=FormApp.openById(FORM_ID)

function resetForm(){
  let items=form.getItems()
  items.forEach(item=>form.deleteItem(item))
}

function createConditionalForm(){
  // reset form
  resetForm()

  let ws=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  let ss=ws.getSheetByName("Feuille 4_sorted") // Feuille 4 sorted by department, city and establishment
  let table=ss.getDataRange().getValues()
  // drop the headers
  table.shift()

  // create array of column A - departments
  let dptOptions=table.map(row=>row[0])
  // get only the unique departments in Column A
  let singleDptOptions=[]
  dptOptions.forEach(option=>{
    if(singleDptOptions.indexOf(option)==-1)
    singleDptOptions.push(option)
  })
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Unique departments:"+singleDptOptions)

  // create question - "select region"
  let departementQuestion = form.addMultipleChoiceItem().setTitle("Select Region")
  
  // create a temporary array for the cities in each region
  let finalDptOptions = []

  // for each dpt/region do something
  singleDptOptions.forEach(dptOption=>{
    // for each region, create a section
    let section=form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle("Region:"+dptOption)
    section.setGoToPage(FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT)

    // create an array of ALL cities cities in each region
    let cityOptions=table.filter(option=>option[0]==dptOption).map(row=>row[1])

    // create a temporary array for the unique cities in each region
    let singleCityOptions=[]
    // create a temporary array for the establishements in each region/dpt city
    let regCitEst = []

    // create an array of UNIQUE cities in each region
    cityOptions.forEach(cityName=>{
      if(singleCityOptions.indexOf(cityName)==-1)
      singleCityOptions.push(cityName)
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: Region = "+dptOption+", city name = "+cityName)
    })

    // create an array of establishments for each unique city
    singleCityOptions.forEach(uniqueCityName=>{
      let regionCityEstablishment = table.filter(option=>option[0]==dptOption && option[1]==uniqueCityName).map(row=>row[2])
      regCitEst.push(regionCityEstablishment)
      Logger.log("DEBUG: Region = "+dptOption+"\ncity name = "+uniqueCityName+"\nestablishments = "+regionCityEstablishment)
    })
  })   
}



Thanks @Tedinoz ! That's great !! In order to create the form I need to add the following part at the end of your code ?
let departementQuestion = form.addMultipleChoiceItem().setTitle("Select Region")
let section=form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle("Region:"+dptOption)
let dptChoice = departementQuestion.createChoice(dptOption, section)
finalDptOptions.push(dptChoice)
departementQuestion.setChoices(finalDptOptions)

duplicate for the establishments ?


To be honest, I don't know. I've spent  (too) many hours trying to debug the "form" component but it's just not my thing. It sounds like the answer by @Saddles creates the complete form (in which case, it is a much better answer than mine). If further development is to be done, I suggest using a small sub-set of the data. But, truly, you are creating an ENORMOUS, unwieldy form that will offer a poor user experience. I strongly suggest exploring alternatives.

Thanks, very clear ! many thanks for your help !
